# Athena Query Results: Are they always strings?

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm in the process of building new "ETL" pipelines with CTAS. Unfortunately, Quite often the CTAS query is too intensive which causes Athena to time out. As such, I use CTAS to create the initial table and populate with a small sample. I then write a script that queries the same table the CTAS was generated from (which is parquet format) for the remaining days that the CTAS couldn’t handle upfront. I write the output of these query results to the same directory that is holding the results of the CTAS query before repairing the table (to pick up new data). However, it seems to be a pretty clunky process for a number of reasons:

1) Query results written out with a standard SQL statements all end up being strings. For example, when I write out the number of DAUs (which is a count and cast to an int) the csv output is a string I.e. wrapped in “”. 
Is it possible to write out Athena "query_results" (not the CTAS)  as anything other than a string when in CSV format. The main problem with this is it means it can't be read back into the table produced by the CTAS since these column expect a bigint. This, of course, can be resolved with a lambda function but seems like a big overhead for something that should be trivial.

2) Can you put query results (not from CTAS) directly into parquet instead of CSV?

3) Is there any way to prevent metadata being generated with the query_results (not from CTAS). Again, it can be cleaned up with a lambda function, but it's just additional nonsense I need to handle.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The data type of the result depends on the SQL used to create it and also on how you consume it. Based on your question I'm going to assume that you're creating a table using CTAS and that the output is CSV, and that you're then looking at the CSV data directly.

That CSV is going to have quotes in it, but that doesn't mean that it's not possible to read integer values as integers, and so on. Athena uses a schema-on-read approach, and as long as the serde can interpret a value as a particular type, that type will work as the type of the column.

If you query the table created by your CTAS operation you should get back integers for the integer columns.

Using CTAS you can also create output of different types, like JSON, Avro, Parquet, and ORC, that keep the type information. Just [use the `format` property to select the output type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html).

I am a bit confused what you mean by your third question. With a normal query you get two files on S3, the data file and the metadata file, and they will be written to the output location given in the `StartQueryExecution` API call, but with a CTAS query you get the output data in a different location (given in the SQL) than the metadata file.

Are you actually using CTAS, or are you talking about the regular query result files?

---

Update after the question got clarified:

1) Athena is unfortunately unable to properly read it's own output in many situations. This is something that really surprises me that they never considered before launch. You might be able to set up a table that uses the regex serde.

2) No, unfortunately the only output of a regular query is CSV at this time.

3) No, the metadata is always written to the same prefix as the output.

I think your best bet is running multiple CTAS queries that select subsets of your source data, if there is a date column for example you could make one CTAS per month or some other time range that works. After the CTAS queries have completed you can move the result files into the same directory on S3 and create a final table that has that directory as its location.

Comment: Hi Theo, I realised my initial query wasn’t very clear. I’ve editing to try add more clarity. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Due to the problems I’ve mentioned above the most sensible flow seems to be. 1) Create an external table 2) run a query 3) fetch the query result (avoid problem 3) 4) clean the query result with pandas (avoid problem 1) 5) push clean result to directory which he table from 1) reads

Comment: thankfully this is now resolved since Athena can now store its query results in parquet or other binary formats.